# Setting class and method variables in the application_controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm having real issues in trying to grab the current_user from devise, determine the account id from here and then pass this as a variable to the set_current_tenant_to method from this gem: https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant.

In my application controller I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details      
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time

  def get_current_account_id
    current_account_user = current_user
    current_account_id = current_account_user.account_id
    current_account_id
  end

  current_account = Account.find(get_current_account_id)
  set_current_tenant_to(current_account)
```

I know that the get_current_account_id deduces the correct account_id because when I place it in a before_filter call I can see in the logs it outputs the correct figure. However when I run this I get the following error:

```
Routing Error

undefined local variable or method `get_current_account_id' for ApplicationController:Class
```

Any advice or pointers on how I can get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it is calling a class level method, not an instance method, so you need to call it on self.  also, you really don't need all those extra variables:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def self.get_current_account_id
    current_user.account_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but it doesn't work.

With this in my controller:

`def self.get_current_account_id
    current_user.account_id
  end

  current_account = Account.find(get_current_account_id)
  set_current_tenant_to(current_account)`

I get the following response now:

`Routing Error

undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for ApplicationController:Class`

Comment: the confusion is from a clash of class vs instance methods... at first glance, the tenant docs look funny as they seem to be running in a class setting, but that would lock the account to the first run rather than run it every request... I suggest clarifying with the author of that gem...

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you wanna do is creating a **filter** to set the current tenant. You should do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_tenant_to_current_account
  def set_tenant_to_current_account
    current_account = Account.find(current_user.account_id)
    set_current_tenant_to(current_account)
  end

  def set_current_tenant_to(account)
    # Your business logic here.
    @current_tenant = account
  end
end
```

EDIT: put some stubbed method code to represent `set_tenant_to`

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought but when I run this I get:

`NoMethodError in FooController#index

undefined method `set_current_tenant_to' for #<FooController:0x007f968e80e608>

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:36:in 'set_tenant_to_current_account'`

Comment: Ok, this happens because you didn't define this method anywhere in your controller. Where are you defining the "set_current_tenant_to" method?

Comment: It is set as part of this gem here:

https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant/blob/master/lib/acts_as_tenant/controller_extensions.rb

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you define any custom method in application controller then you must call it using this

call.

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   before_filter :get_current_account_id


    protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection     
   helper :all # include all helpers, all the time

   def get_current_account_id
    current_account_user = current_user
    current_account_id = current_account_user.account_id
    set_tentant_id(current_account_id)
   end

   def set_tentant_id
    #your logic
   end
 end
```

I hope it will work very clean and fine.....